# Client (Tomcat) calls Stateless Session Bean (JBoss), how to handle Client Identifier

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0, ejb, jaas

we have the following setup:

- Tomcat (Web App) calls a service (Stateless Session Bean) in JBoss 5.1.0 EAP (EJB 3.0)
- JBoss has two different Persistence Contexts defined using two different databases
- The JBoss Service needs to know which client called its service, something like an identifier (multi tenancy?)

we could change all service methods on the Jboss side to accept a client identifier as parameter. then we would need to change every possible method call inside the service to transport this identifier, which to me sounds too much of a hassle.

first i thought about something similar to a ThreadLocal variable... which i guess is forbidden in the world of Java EE.

do you guys know of any elegant solution of "transporting" a client identifier? i think JAAS does something similar by which every call from the "outside" world is filtered and user credentials are applied to every call. once the call enters the "Jboss service world" all subsequent method invocations have the caller identification.

i want my application to be as "client agnostic" as possible it should just get the right config "injected" (like the persistence context) depending on which client called a service. the logic will be the same, just the resources its using are different (some kind of interceptor architecture).

i am a bit lost. any help is highly appreciated.

cheers
marcel

Answer (score 0):

From an @AroundInvoke interceptor, you should be able to detect webservices by checking the contents of InvocationContext.getContextData(), which is shared with the webservice context per the JAX-WS spec.  You would still have to propagate it internally.

ThreadLocal in Java EE isn't necessarily bad so long as you remember to clean up after yourself:

```
tl.set(something);
try {
  deepMethodCallHierarchy();
} finally {
  tl.remove();
}
```

(Of course, explicitly passing the context around is probably the cleanest.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. we aren't using webservices. just plain RMI  by using the exported service interface (*.class) via JNDI lookup. any idea?

Comment: looks like we could use the "TransactionSynchronizationRegistry". an example can be found here: http://www.scribd.com/doc/55889067/106/ThreadLocal-Strategy -> Context Holder Pattern

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I'm not sure how I misread your first bullet as saying "webservice", but I did.